# How to open new tab or open new window in an already visible GUI on button press?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm wondering how you open a new tab/window in an already opened GUI with Netbeans.

Also the game I am trying to make will have 1 question per window and have 4 answer buttons you can choose from, if you get the correct answer your score is kept in a variable that can be used throughout the entire code.

```
**package pokemontrivia;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class triviagui extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public triviagui() {
        initComponents();
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
          setTitle("Pokemon Trivia Game");
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setSize(600, 480);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
          quitButton.addActionListener(new CloseListener());
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        easyqestionsLabel = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        mediumqestionsLabel = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        hardqestionsLabel = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        playButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        playButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        playButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        quitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        settingsButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setText("Welcome to Pokemon Trivia !");

        easyqestionsLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        easyqestionsLabel.setText("Easy Questions");

        mediumqestionsLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        mediumqestionsLabel.setText("Medium Questions");

        hardqestionsLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        hardqestionsLabel.setText("Hard Questions");

        playButton3.setText("Play !");

        playButton2.setText("Play !");

        playButton1.setText("Play !");

        quitButton.setText("Quit");

        settingsButton.setText("Settings");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(mediumqestionsLabel)
                        .addComponent(playButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(easyqestionsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(hardqestionsLabel)
                            .addComponent(playButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(playButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(settingsButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(quitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(84, 84, 84))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(127, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {easyqestionsLabel, hardqestionsLabel, mediumqestionsLabel});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(settingsButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                        .addComponent(quitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(easyqestionsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(playButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(mediumqestionsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(playButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(hardqestionsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(playButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(69, 69, 69))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {playButton1, playButton2, playButton3});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(triviagui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(triviagui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(triviagui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(triviagui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new triviagui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField easyqestionsLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField hardqestionsLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField mediumqestionsLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton playButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton playButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton playButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton quitButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton settingsButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}**
```

Comment: [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) was made for this

Comment: @MadProgrammer Gave a great tip, but if it is *always* one question with 4 answers, I'd tend to simply have a `JLabel` for the question and 4 x `JRadioButton` objects in a button group for the answers.  When the user selects an answer, and is informed of right/wrong, change the text (usinf `setText()`) of the question and possible answers.  This has the advantage of only requiring a single panel for as many as thousands of questions.

Answer (score 3):

I'd tend to simply have a `JLabel` for the question and 4 x `JRadioButton` objects in a button group for the answers.  When the user selects an answer and is informed of right/wrong, change the text (using `setText()`) of the question and possible answers.

This has the advantage of only requiring a single panel for as many as thousands of questions.

If it is necessary to have one panel for the question and another for the result, then use a `CardLayout` with two cards.  One for the questions, the other for the answers.

This [short example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556) shows how to use a `CardLayout`.

[image][image]

Comment: thanks that helps a lot but for my project in particular i need to be able to read in the questions from an array list that has 30 questions in it and change the question to the JLabel. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I dont really understand that but i will try it out